# Faster data.table operations

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to collate best practices for faster data table operations. I currently use the following code to aggregate data using a data.table:

```
cardata2<-as.data.table(mtcars)
groups_temp<-c("vs","gear")
eval_formula<-"mileage=sum(mpg), avg_wt=mean(wt)"
cardata2[, eval(parse(text=paste('.(', eval_formula, ')'))) , by=groups_temp]
```

The evaluation formula and group names are dynamic

Is there a better way to aggregate that can make my code run faster? I intend to use this for very large datasets.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: a (very small) performance gain could be achieved by using `paste0` in stead of `paste`. from `?paste:` paste0(..., collapse) is equivalent to paste(..., sep = "", collapse), slightly more efficiently.

Comment: Your `eval_formula` is currently not generic, i.e., it uses the names of specific variables/columns. Therefore, you could skip all the eval part and directly use `.(...)`. As long as you need to specify the colulmns `mpg` and `wt` manually in your `evalute_formula` there is no need to complicate things by using an eval construct. Maybe you could try to set up a generic function for selecting variables and aggreating, this would be the core question of interest behind your question, which you might rephrase towards more general functionality.

Comment: Not sure if I understand your comment correctly. The intention is to provide a generic way of defining columns for aggregation. For example, if I want to only calculate 'average mileage', my formula would change to eval_formula<-"avg_mileage=mean(mpg) while everything else can remain the same.

Comment: you might want to check out `?Gforce`. Hence, something like `cardata2[, lapply(.SD, sum), by=groups_temp, .SDcols="mpg", verbose=TRUE]` will be faster.

Comment: Fyi typo should be `?GForce` (with capital F) in chinsoon's comment. Re your main idea, the usual approach is to use `ee = quote(list(mileage = sum(mpg))); cardata2[, eval(ee), by=groups_temp, verbose=TRUE]`

Comment: The `GForce` will be with you if you `eval(parse` the entirety of the expression, i.e. `eval(parse(text = paste0('cardata2[...')))`.